# Is it considered bad practice to use ID's for "modules" in your CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I know a lot of people preach against using ID's in your styling because they add too much specificity.

However, if you're working with a component that could be placed on any page or any container, isn't this a good thing if used carefully? Am I overlooking something?

The last project I did I used the SMACSS approach to modularize everything. This worked well except there where cases where I had to intentionally add extra specificity.

Example using SCSS:

```
#myWidget {
  .foo { 
    width: 150px;
  }
  ...
}
```

Where in some cases this can be overridden fairly

```
.myWidget {
  .foo {
    width: 150px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule is that an ID should only be present on the page once (`#main-navigation` for a `<div>` containing your site's navigation for example) and classes can be present on the page multiple times (`.red-text` to give some text a red color for example). I personally tend to use IDs to separate out different container level sections, whereas classes can be applied more generally.

Your examples do not contain valid CSS however... you would need to write them like this:

```
#myWidget .foo { 
    width: 150px;
}
```

or

```
.myWidget .foo { 
    width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Ah, yea I forgot about the possibility of multiple instances of a module on a given page. While using backbone, it's really made me reconsider making my css very modular so I can pop in a subview anywhere.

Comment: Doh, I didn't catch myself.... I was writing SCSS...tisk tisk!